# confused with <T>

Tags: c#, generics

watched tutorial from sebastian lague for pathfiending.and code example

```
public class Heap<T> where T : HeapIndex<T>
{

}
public interface HeapIndex<T> : IComparable<T>
{
    int IndexHeap
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
public class Node : HeapIndex<Node> 
{
    public int IndexHeap { get; set; }

    public int CompareTo([AllowNull] Node other)
    {
        return IndexHeap.CompareTo(other.IndexHeap);
    }
}
```

and `Heap<Node> heapNode = new Heap<Node>();`
all its work. i start read for  and i confused. why i cant do with this way

```
public class NodeInt : HeapIndex<int>
{
    public int IndexHeap { get; set; }

    public int CompareTo([AllowNull] int other)
    {
        return IndexHeap.CompareTo(other);
    }
}
        NodeInt nd = new NodeInt();
        HeapIndex<NodeInt> hpD = nd as HeapIndex<NodeInt>;
        Heap<NodeInt> heapInt = hpD as Heap<NodeInt>;
```

bacause its not work `Heap<NodeInt> heapNodeInt = new Heap<NodeInt>();`
I probably just do not fully understand, and terribly blurred my eyes. but I thought that his code works, any instance that meets the requirement where T is an interface implementation, then you can use it to create a heap
why i cant just `Heap<NodeInt> heapNodeInt = new Heap<NodeInt>();`

Comment: There is a constraint on T to be a `HeapIndex<T>`.  `Heap<Node>` is ok because `Node` implements `HeapIndex<Node>`.  If you want `Heap<NodeInt>`, then `NodeInt` must implement `HeapIndex<NodeInt>`

Answer (score 2):

`Heap<T> where T : HeapIndex<T>` means that if you want `Heap<NodeInt>`, then the `NodeInt` should inherit `HeapIndex<NodeInt>` just because `T = NodeInt` in the `Heap` declaration. But your `NodeInt` is `HeapIndex<int>`, so it does not meet requirement and this code won't compile.

Comment: thanks at the morning i was understand more clearly